# Select left join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my php session:

```
$get_user = $_SESSION['id']; //id of the user that logged in
```

my query is:

```
$query_select = "SELECT i.users_id,s.seen, CONCAT_WS(' ', i.users_fname, i.users_lname)
AS full_name
FROM tbl_request AS f
LEFT JOIN tbl_usersinfo AS i ON i.users_id = f.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_status AS s ON s.user_id = f.user_id 
WHERE (f.user_id = $get_user || f.another_user = $get_user) && f.status = 'accepted'
GROUP BY full_name ORDER BY seen DESC
```

tbl_request:

```
user_id    another_user   status
1               2        'accepted'
1               5        'accepted'
3               1         'waiting'
4               1         'accepted'
```

tbl_usersinfo

```
users_id    users_fname       users_lname
1              michael            jackson
2              michael            jordan
3              bat                man
4              will               smith
5              sean               kingston
```

tbl_status

```
user_id     seen
1           'online'
2            'offline'
3            'online'
4            'online'
5            'offline'
```

lets assume that the session is equal to 1, this query will result to:

```
users_id   full_name     seen
4          will smith    online
```

it should be:

```
 users_id   full_name            seen
    2       michael jordan       offline
    4       will smith           online
    5       sean kingston        offline
```

I want to select all status that equals to "accepted", but the query above only displays when the session is equal to another_user. I want my query to be flexible. for example, when the session is equal to the user_id, it should choose the another_user instead because that's the id of his friend.

Comment: Can you give an example of the output of the query?

Comment: just remove f.another_user = $get_user

Comment: It will only return the user id = '1', the query should choose the another_user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that in your `LEFT JOIN`s you always compare to the `f.user_id`, but it should be `f.user_id` only if your `$get_user` is in `another_user` column... and also the same in other way... I suggest you to remake complete your query...

There are many ways to do this, but maybe simplier will be to use `UNION`:

```
SELECT i.users_id,s.seen, CONCAT_WS(' ', i.users_fname, i.users_lname)
AS full_name
FROM tbl_request AS f
LEFT JOIN tbl_usersinfo AS i ON i.users_id = f.another_user
LEFT JOIN tbl_status AS s ON s.user_id = f.another_user 
WHERE f.user_id = $get_user && f.status = 'accepted'
UNION
SELECT i.users_id,s.seen, CONCAT_WS(' ', i.users_fname, i.users_lname)
AS full_name
FROM tbl_request AS f
LEFT JOIN tbl_usersinfo AS i ON i.users_id = f.user_id
LEFT JOIN tbl_status AS s ON s.user_id = f.user_id 
WHERE f.another_user = $get_user && f.status = 'accepted'
GROUP BY full_name ORDER BY seen DESC
```

Comment: WOOOOOOWW, thank you siiiirr you're a life saveeer :))) I've been trying to figure this out for like 2 hours.